# Should a table with only one column have a primary key?

Tags: sql

For example, I have a table called `programs` and another called `format`. The `format` tables contains a single column called format, which has three possible values: zip, rar and exe. Should the format table have a primary key?

Comment: with another table called applications, with a foreign key to format.

Comment: This is called premature optimization. For 3 values it doesn't matter. Overall the usage of one column tables with primary key is justified in many situations. Not necessarily best practice, but in this case it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Think what happens if your table would contain:

```
zip
rar
exe
exe
```

If you see no problem then your table does not need a PK.

Comment: i dont see a problem with two exe

Comment: but do you see a value in having two exe?

Answer (score 0):

If the values are unique, then perhaps not. However, if you do not have a unique index on the values, you could have duplicates, and that would make it difficult to identify single rows. Also, using a PK with a known, fixed length (such as an integer ID) will help with performance and keep index fragmentation down. Plus, if you need to join to this table, you're better off referencing the ID of a format rather than the value, by using a foreign key (which in some RDBMS requires a PK).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table called `Programs` and a table called `Format` with a bunch of values, why not just have a `FormatId` column in the `Program` table and use one of the (currently three) foreign key values in the `Format` table?

See these notes about Normalisation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization (I'm sure you know this, but maybe somebody else reading the question might not).

Answer (score 0):

The table with only one column would have unique values in most of the cases, as repeating value and that too in a single column does not make sense.

So, in your cases, the format would not be repeating (thats what I think), so there is no harm in making primary key but

1) It imposes an indexing on that field (do you want that?)

2) In future, if you are planning to link this to another table, then make sure you use this as a primary key and not introducing anything like format_id for the primary key. If you do so, then please dont make this as a primary key right now.

Comment: should i just make it unique then? i will be foreign keying it to another table